# Issue with selector in Ajax result using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a page that contains some cube...
When user click on the cubes, the cube's width and height will change and the related content will fetch using Ajax.
The Ajax result is another html page itself, that have some jQuery commands.
Please look at the `result` page:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapperProducts">
<div class="products" id="mainContent">

  </div><!-- # mainContent -->
  <div class="products" id="rightPanel">

  </div><!-- # rightPanel -->
  <div class="products" id="footerPanel">

    <div class="arr" id="arrowRightFooter">
       <img src="images/arrows/light/arrowRight.png" width="30" height="30"  alt=""/>
     </div><!-- # arrowRightFooter -->

    <div id="thumbWrapper">
        <div class="thumb" id="t1">

        </div><!-- # t1 -->
        <div class="thumb" id="t2">

        </div><!-- # t2 -->
        <div class="thumb" id="t3">

        </div><!-- # t3 -->
        <div class="thumb" id="t4">

        </div><!-- # t4 -->
        <div class="thumb" id="t5">

        </div><!-- $ t5 -->
        <div class="thumb" id="t6">

        </div><!-- # t6 -->
        <div class="thumb" id="t7">

        </div><!-- # t7 -->
        <div class="thumb" id="t8">

        </div><!-- # t8 -->
        <div class="thumb" id="t9">

        </div><!-- # t9 -->
     </div><!-- # thumbWrapper-->

     <div class="arr" id="arrowLeftFooter">
       <img src="images/arrows/light/arrowLeft.png" width="30" height="30"  alt=""/>
     </div><!-- # arrowLeftFooter -->

  </div><!-- # footerPanel -->
```

and **CSS:**

```
div#logo div#wrapperProducts {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:url(../images/27.jpg) no-repeat;

}
div#logo div#wrapperProducts div#mainContent {
    left:0;
    top:60px;
    width:80%;
    height:70%;
    float:left;
    /*background-color:red;*/   
}
div#logo div#wrapperProducts div#rightPanel {
    right:-10px;
    top:0;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
    position:absolute;
    /*background-color:blue;*/  
}
div#logo div#wrapperProducts div#footerPanel {
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:80%;
    height:30%;
    /*background-color:#096;*/
}
div#logo div#wrapperProducts div#thumbWrapper {
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
    margin:auto;
    margin-right:5%;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    /*background-color:;*/
}
div#logo div#wrapperProducts div#thumbWrapper .thumb {
    width:170px;
    height:100%;
    margin-right:2px;
    right:0;
    display:inline-block;/*inline-block*/
    position:relative;
    direction:rtl;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255, 0.2), rgba(255,255,255, 0) );
    background-color:transparent;

}
div#logo div#wrapperProducts div#footerPanel div.arr {
    position:absolute;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
div#logo div#wrapperProducts div#footerPanel #arrowRightFooter {
    right:0;
    bottom:50%; 
}
div#logo div#wrapperProducts div#footerPanel #arrowLeftFooter {
    left:0;
    bottom:50%; 
}
```

`div#logo` is the main page element`


and **JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  /*"use strict";*/

$('#logo').css({'background':'none'});
  $('#arrowRightFooter').click( function(){


        console.log('The click button work fine');
        $('.thumb').animate({left: '+=170px' }, 1500);

    });
});
```

This lines are `#logo`'s structure in `main page:`

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parts" id="part1">

    <div class="third" id="left">

      <div class="mostatil radif1" id="logo">

            <div class="imgWrapper">
              <img src="images/icons/new/basketStore.png" width="120" height="90"  alt=""/>
            </div>
      </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background:url(../images/background.png) no-repeat;
    background-color:rgb(24,1,83);
    font-family:"B Koodak", Tahoma;
}

div.parts {
    width:620px;
    height:800px;
    position:absolute;
}

div#part1 {
    margin-left:150px;
}

div.third {
    width:510px;
    height:640px;
    margin-top:100px;
}

div#left {
    margin-left:55px;   
}

div.third div.mostatil {
    width:250px;
    height:120px;   
}

div.third#left div.radif1 {
    margin-top:0px; 
}

div#logo {
    background-color:rgb(214,164,1);
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

and **jQuery: **

```
/*/-------------  C L I C K    ON    DIV # L O G O  --------------/*/
$(document).on('click', 'div.mostatil#logo', function(){

        $('div.moraba, div.mostatil').not('#logo').delay(500).fadeOut('fast');/**/

        var detail = {};
        detail.id               = $(this).attr('id');
        detail.class           = $(this).attr('class').substr(7);
        $(this)
                .animate({
                    width:         WinWidth,
                    height:           WinHeight,
                    marginTop:   -60,
                    marginLeft:  -210
                }, 100, 'easeOutQuint', false)
                .data({ id: detail.id, class: detail.class})
                .css({'z-index':500, 'cursor':'default'})
                .transition({rotateY:'360deg'}, 1000,'snap');

        $('body').css('overflow','hidden');

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"pages/Ajax/products.php",
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#logo').html('LOADING; PLEASE WAIT...')
            },
            statusCode: {
                404: function(){
                    $(this).html('Page not found');
                }
            },
            success: function(result) {
                $('#logo').html(result);
            }
        });//Ajax


});
```

When I select other elements of result page like `wrapperProduct` or `mainContent` or etc..., the animate method works fine, but just in `$('.thumb')`, there is no result after click on arrow divs...
I think there is something wrong in my css, may be with `whitespace:nowrap`, because it's first time I'm using this command...
I believe it's because of misunderstanding CSS concepts by me...
Please guide me to the write way and help to figure out my fault...
**Thanks in advance...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there's issue with `AJAX`...
There is not any thing wrong with selectors,
 you've defined that the application send an Ajax request to the server and insert the `HTML` result in this div again with every click on `div.mostatila#logo`...!!!
So,
when you click on every place inside the page, you are clicking on the `#logo` in fact...

you have to limit the Ajax request to a situation, for example:

```
        if ( $(this).css('width') == '250px' ) {
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:"pages/Ajax/products.php",
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#logo').html('LOADING; PLEASE WAIT...')
                },
                statusCode: {
                    404: function(){
                        $(this).html('Page Not Found...');
                    }
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#logo').html(result).css('background','none');
                }
            });//Ajax
        }
        else {
            return; 
        }
```

then, when the `#logo` have `width:250px`, Ajax request will sent...
I think this is the problem...